# (C++) Dont use header files

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm having a general question about header files:

In my project, which is not a library or plugin, but a standalone program, I don't use any header files - I am just using cpp files that I include in my main file.

Should I dismiss this coding style for some obscure reasons? I mean, I get that using header files can be helpful when navigating among classes or functions, so you can get a quick lookaround, but I generally think just declaring the classes "as they are" feels better for me - for navigation I'm using comments and the find function of gedit (I am not using an IDE either, for the same reason)^^. But will I at some time maybe run into problems if I continue with this? My Project is expanding, but as I mentioned, I don't see a problem regarding header files about it.

Comment: "I am just using cpp files that I include in my main file" ..... don't do that ever. Seriously. You'll never be able to make a program of any reasonable size.

Comment: Kk looks like I might rewrite some code... thanks